# Tradingview widget - logarithmic scale as default

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

Is there a way to change default linear scale to logarithmic in advanced tradingview widget?
https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/

I would appriciate any help
Thank you

Comment: This is a question to be answered by the tradingview documentation.